# Internet Explorer 9 displaying CSS sprite image, but with strange content

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, css-sprites

I've got an image sprite that I'm using, but IE9 isn't displaying it properly.

It works fine in Firefox, but displays the grey border and symbol over top the image (as shown). It also doesn't quite work in Chrome - it displays the image, but has the grey border with it.

here's the CSS code that grabs it:

```
#see_more_vendors {
background:url('vendor_sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 0px; height: 60px; width:135px; display:block;}
```

this is the html:

```
<td><a href="#"><img id="see_more_vendors" alt=""/></a>
```

(I've removed the leading address of the image, as that isn't the problem.)

Initially, I thought it was the border, since in Chrome it was only showing the grey border. But then, I saw it in Internet Explorer, and I haven't seen a case like this online.

This is what the image looks like, when it should have no border and no icon in the top left corner.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/examplec.jpg/

Comment: What does the HTML code for `#see_more_vendors` look like?

Comment: Please give a working example (with fully qualified image paths http://) here or on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I edited question to include the html now

Comment: the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jqkVR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this more than 1 times then make class in css:

```
.see_more_vendors {
background:url('vendor_sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 0px; height: 60px; width:135px;display:block;}
```

And then your A tag should look like this:

```
<a class="see_more_vendors" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```

Because as you can see on your posted image (imageshack) you see background but no image. because `img` tag `src` is empty.
Well i use `&nbsp;` if you know better way then tell me. Thanks.

Comment: That did it. Thank you sir. I wasn't inserting an image, but was just setting the background image behind the container.